# VIDEO CHAT REACT APP: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I've tried reading through other similar questions but nothing that I've found seems to do the trick.
I keep receiving this error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null
at addVideoStream (script.js:33)
at script.js:17

Chrome has asked me for camera and audio permission. To test what was wrong, I set myVideo.muted = false to see if it was also not receiving my audio but that seems to work.

I don't know how to make my video stream not be null. Please help.

**Here is my entire script.js code:**

```
const socket = io("/"); // connects to root path of our app
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: "/",
  port: "3001",
});

const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true; // so we don't hear our own voice play back to us

navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
  });

myPeer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
});

socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
  console.log("User connected: " + userId);
});

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    video.play();
  });
  videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

**and my html code:**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script>
      const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>";
    </script>
    <script
      defer
      src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #video-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
        grid-auto-rows: 300px;
      }

      video {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="#video-grid"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help and patience, I'm new to this. I did my best trying to research but wasn't able to find anything as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` attribute's value should be `video-grid` instead of `#video-grid`. Your error is due to a typo.